# why does jwplayer only work on local server?

Tags: jwplayer, windows-server

I am using jw player 5.9 (have to use that version).  I thought I had everything working until I realized that the videos don't work unless I am opening up the browser on localserver (windows 2003).  I use full DNS when opening and all works perfect on local host.

When trying to get to the site otherwise, IE10 just gives me a black screen - nothing at all and safari/FF give me error - "Error loading skin: Skin not a valid file type".

So is this some kind of perms issue with the zip template or something?  I have users set to full control...

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running the player? The player should work on any type of server, local or on the web. I have used it on a local apache install, as well as on a few sites.

Comment: @EthanLongTail  It is on an internal web server - windows 2003.  When I play it on the web server with IE8 everything is perfect.  When I try to play it on our intranet I get just the skin in IE10 (black screen with toolbar) or the skin error in every other type of browser.  I have to use that version too because we have like 30 programs using it and our license is for it.  Seems like some perm issue to me but can't figure it out.  The HTML and videos are on another server if that matters too.  I run both servers - one is our file server and the other does our web apps.

Comment: I would need to see something to debug this further then.

Comment: @EthanLongTail I could post some files but there is no way to show you - do files or screenshots help?

Comment: I would need to see something in action. You can't update from 5.9 to 5.10?

Comment: Well I just need to use the zip template and the multiplayer js they have so I guess I could try that upgrade.  Where are the files for that at?

Comment: Licensed is at - http://www.longtailvideo.com/order/view

Comment: Hence one of the issues.  We are a very very large company.  This was originally setup on a server that our group doesn't own.  That server went down, so I am just trying to reproduce the jwplayer files that were on that server.  I have no idea why they weren't set up on my group's server but before my time.  No idea who this is registered to and doing it on W2003 makes it a mess but we can't change a bunch of links in the middle of a program.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can email us and we can look up your old license information - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us